# TypeError: User.createUser is not a function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, postman

I am currently running MongoDB shell version 3.4.7 and I keep getting this error of createUser not being a function where User is an object created like so from a different folder

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    email: {type:String, required: true},
    username:{type: String, required: true},
    password:{type: String, required: true}
});
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

and used like so.

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) =>{
    let newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    User.createUser(newUser, (err, user) =>{
       if(err){
           res.json({success: false, msg: "Failed to register user"});
       } else{
           res.json({success: true, msg: "User registered"});
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: post your exact error message

Comment: `User.create()` should work

Answer (score 0):

In your second file where you are using User instance you should include
following line before proceeding

```
var User = require('../models/user');
```